# greenplum gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host

Tags: greenplum

when I set up greenplum, I used the command  *gpinitsystem -c gpinitsystem_config*

```
[gpadmin@w01v ~]$ gpinitsystem -c gpinitsystem_config
20160603:16:50:49:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, please wait...
20160603:16:50:50:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Reading Greenplum configuration file gpinitsystem_config
20160603:16:50:50:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Locale has not been set in gpinitsystem_config, will set to default value
20160603:16:50:50:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Locale set to en_US.utf8
20160603:16:50:51:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No DATABASE_NAME set, will exit following template1 updates
20160603:16:50:51:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-MASTER_MAX_CONNECT not set, will set to default value 250
20160603:16:50:51:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, Completed
20160603:16:50:52:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, please wait...
...
20160603:16:50:52:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Configuring build for standard array
20160603:16:50:52:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing multi-home checks, Completed
20160603:16:50:53:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building primary segment instance array, please wait...
......
20160603:16:50:56:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building group mirror array type , please wait...
......
20160603:16:51:01:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking Master host
20160603:16:51:01:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking new segment hosts, please wait...
............
20160603:16:51:13:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking new segment hosts, Completed
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum Database Creation Parameters
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master Configuration
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master instance name       = wl_measure
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master hostname            = w01v.white.xxx.xxx.net
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master port                = 5432
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master instance dir        = /home/gpadmin/masterdata/gpseg-1
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master LOCALE              = en_US.utf8
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum segment prefix   = gpseg
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master Database            = 
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master connections         = 250
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master buffers             = 128000kB
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Segment connections        = 750
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Segment buffers            = 128000kB
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checkpoint segments        = 8
20160603:16:51:14:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Encoding                   = UNICODE
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Postgres param file        = Off
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Initdb to be used          = /usr/local/greenplum-db/./bin/initdb
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-GP_LIBRARY_PATH is         = /usr/local/greenplum-db/./lib
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Ulimit check               = Passed
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Array host connect type    = Single hostname per node
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master IP address [1]      = 10.143.13.158
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby Master             = w01v.white.bjcc.qihoo.net
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Primary segment #          = 2
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby IP address         = 10.143.13.158
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total Database segments    = 6
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Trusted shell              = ssh
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Number segment hosts       = 3
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror port base           = 43000
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Replicaton port base       = 34000
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror replicaton port base= 44000
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror segment #           = 2
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirroring config           = ON
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirroring type             = Group
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:----------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:15:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum Primary Segment Configuration
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:----------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w01v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg0    33000   2  0    34000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w01v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg1    33001   3  1    34001
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w02v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg2    33000   4  2    34000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w02v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg3    33001   5  3    34001
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w03v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg4    33000   6  4    34000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w03v     /home/gpadmin/segmentdata/gpseg5    33001   7  5    34001
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum Mirror Segment Configuration
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w02v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg0  43000   8  0    44000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w02v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg1  43001   9  1    44001
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w03v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg2  43000   10 2    44000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w03v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg3  43001   11 3    44001
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w01v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg4  43000   12 4    44000
20160603:16:51:16:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-w01v     /home/gpadmin/segdatamirror/gpseg5  43001   13 5    44001
Continue with Greenplum creation Yy/Nn>
y
20160603:16:51:45:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building the Master instance database, please wait...
20160603:16:52:04:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting the Master in admin mode
20160603:16:52:28:gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host /usr/local/greenplum-db/. Script Exiting!
20160603:16:52:28:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Script has left Greenplum Database in an incomplete state
20160603:16:52:28:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Run command /bin/bash /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/backout_gpinitsystem_gpadmin_20160603_165049 to remove these changes
20160603:16:52:28:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20160603:16:52:28:013336 gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
```

It returns

> gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host

Can anybody helps me ? Thanks

Comment: first, run the "verbose" mode of installed (i.e. with `-v`). Second, make sure that all the hosts you have in list are available using the hostname you provided

Comment: One problem you have is the standby master.  The standby master must be a different host than the master.  It isn't required either so if you are just building something for testing, then you can remove it from the config.  Same goes with mirroring.  Secondly, it is a little odd to use a node for both the master and a segment.  It would be better to use w01v as the master and w02v and w03v as the segment hosts.  Lastly, have you exchanged keys yet with these three hosts?  Did that work correctly?  Did you add the host names to /etc/hosts on all nodes?

Answer (score 1):

```
20160603:16:52:28:gpinitsystem:w01v:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Unknown host /usr/local/greenplum-db/. Script Exiting!
```

This line indicates that you have denoted "/usr/local/greenplum-db/" as a hostname. Check your hostfile or configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have no extra spaces before or after your hostname(S) in the host file.

Answer (score 0):

Make entries in host file. And try to share or ping hostname. To check it's working

Answer (score -2):

Problem Description
[image: Problem Description:]

You can edit the "`$GPHOME/bin/gpinitsystem`" file.

After :
[image: After：]

Comment: LOG_MSG "TEST TEST GP_HOSTNAME: $GP_HOSTNAME"
                GP_HOSTNAME="sdw"
                LOG_MSG "TEST TEST GP_HOSTNAME: $GP_HOSTNAME"
                PING_HOST $GP_HOSTNAME

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please always type the actual error message in your question. Links to images / other sites can break in the future.